# Ios taking snapshot of a screen after cropping some parts

Tags: ios, image, crop

Yep as the title says I need to take a cropped snapshot of my app.

I want to cut top of the screenshot little bit (%20) I already have a code which I used to take a snapshot and send it to facebook and its working but its taking the photo of all of the screen so how can tell my code to ignore the %20 percent of the screen.Maybe with height and width also I looked some questions in the stack overflow and manage to slide my screenshot so I get rid of the unwanted part at the top but this time at the bottom huge white area appeared so it didnt solve my problem.

Here is my snapshot code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.ekran.bounds.size);
    [self.ekran.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method to crop the image, that accepts any frame to crop the image against

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {    
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Use it as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.ekran.bounds.size);
[self.ekran.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGFloat imgHight = resultingImage.size.height;

// Create a frame that crops the top 20% of the image
CGRect* imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, imgHight -  (imgHight*0.8), width, imgHight*0.8);

resultingImage = [self cropImage:resultingImage toRect:imageFrame];
```